# ImportError: No module named 'ronshome.wsgi'

Tags: python, django, installation, python-3.5, uwsgi

I am completing [these steps](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) to setup my first Django web site.  I've made it to the "[Test your Django project](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#test-your-django-project)" section.

The command

```
python3 manage.py runserver 192.168.0.53:8080
```

runs successfully.  I am able to browse / navigate the new web site.  I've been unable to make the next command

```
uwsgi --http :8000 --module mysite.wsgi
```

work.  I've tried to slightly modify it to match my venv:

```
uwsgi --http :8000 --module ronshome.wsgi:application
```

This creates the error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'ronshome.wsgi'
```

I re-confirmed the success of:

```
pip3 install uwsgi
```

which outputs:

```
Requirement already satisfied: uwsgi in ./ronshome/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

I did the command

```
find . -name \*.txt -print
```

The file **ronshome.wsgi** does not exist within website folder.

I used **ronshome** as the name of the venv.  I am not understanding how to proceed with the deployment of uWsgi

Comment: It looks like it's just a problem with the python path. What's the full path to your `wsgi.py`?

Comment: @WillKeeling It turned out to be 2 things.  You were correct about the Python Path.  Issue #2: There was package I needed to add to my Debian server.  Thank you Will.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like:

```
uwsgi --http :8000 --module application_path:wsgi_filename -H /path/to/virtualenv
```

Where,

- **application_path**: is the module (or folder including an `__init__.py` file)
- **wsgi_filename**: is the name of the file containing the application wsgi loader.

Most likely, your `wsgi.py` file would look like:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
# note --> application_path
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "application_path.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Good luck!